# What is the difference between "shut" and "close"?

Tags: word-meaning, difference

It is obvious that **shut** and **close** are very similar in meaning. However, while learning English as non-native (a long time ago) the teacher underlined that the two words are not identical in meaning.

I was unable to find a "clear" explanation about this difference yet - so I am still confused.

I found:

- the definitions of the words;
- how the words are similar;

**I did not find: how are these words different.**

---

Edit: Based on the answers and on the comments, is it safe to assume that there is no "general" rule about when to use "shut" and "close"? And that one must learn the "correct" verb for each situation separately?

Comment: Related question:[Shut and close your mouth](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/38183/9161)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> *You can shut the window
>
>   You can close the door
>
>   You can close a highway
>
>   But you cannot shut the store*

The verb *close* is an antonym for *open*. Therefore, we can say things like:

- Why did you **close** (or *shut*) the window? Please open it again.
- Please **shut** (or *close*) the door. Otherwise, the cat might get out.

In addition to doors, windows, briefcases, and cages, though, we can also open and close things like highways, runways, and restaurants. In this sense of the word, *shut* does not function like an antonym – at least, not in American English (the following examples don’t seem to hold true in British English, based on some informative comments beneath my original answer):

- Oak Street is **closed** due to flooding. We will have to find another way there.
  (**NOT**: Oak Street is *shut*...)
- The restaurant is **closed**. Let’s go find someplace else to eat.
  (**NOT**: The restaurant is *shut...*)

As an aside, the phrasal verb *shut down* can be used in a similar way as *closed*, but that often connotes a longer period of inaccessibility:

- That restaurant was shut down three months ago.

Put another way, a pub may have a **closing time**, but it will not have a **shutting time**.

Comment: Your English must be different from mine. While I agree that "close" is more common in those cases, "shut the road/shop/airport" seem perfectly normal to me.Searching the GloWbE corpus, I get 60 instances of "close the road" (including 18 in the UK) against 8 of "shut the road" (6 in the UK, the other two in Nigeria and the Philippines), and similar patterns with "airport". (It's a bit hard to compare "store", because in the relevant sense, the BrE word for "store" is "shop", which isn't much used in that sense in AmE. But I think I see the same pattern.

Comment: We certainly say shut for all those meanings of close or closed, in my experience, in British English.

Comment: (except "shutting time", but "closing time" is just a specific phrase; people often ask "when do you shut?" in shops)

Comment: To lend some weight to the usage of *shut* in those scenarios: the phrase "the way is shut" features pretty prominently in *The Lord of the Rings*. Tolkein had a degree in English with first class honours, and is known for his understanding and command of language. If he thought it was a valid use of the word, I'm inclined to agree with him.

Comment: @ColinFine et al. - Thanks for the clarification! This differentiation seems to apply to AmE only. Very interesting.

Comment: Things that can be "closed" that can't be "shut" can still typically be "shut down".

Comment: shut and close roads, stores, shops etc. However, if the closing is definitive, I'd say close the store over shut. And I really don't think there is any BrE, AmE thing going on here. Often, something that is shut involves a moving part (shut the valve, with or without off). Shutting time is odd in both.

Comment: @anaximander: Agreed, but note that his usage of "shut" there was, if anything, even more unusual and archaic than most dialogue in LotR.

Comment: Note that headlines, even in AmE, frequently use "shut" instead of "closed" or "shut down".

Comment: What Colin says about shut/close is the same for AmE.

Answer (score 11):

The words have a sense which is completely identical, as seen in "shut/close the door". However, *close* can be used in another way, too.

> If we accelerate, we can **close the gap**.

Essentially, *close* can be used to represent openings becoming smaller or objects getting closer. Usually based on the phrase ***close the gap***. It can also be used metaphorically, as in "close the gender pay gap". You cannot use *shut* for this sense. Likewise, *shut* is used in certain instances where *close* would not be acceptable:

> I've had enough of your lip, just **shut up** now!

(*Shut up* meaning "stop talking"; *lip* in this instance meaning impudent speech. *Shut up* is idiomatic in most if not all varieties of English; *lip* in this instance may be British-specific. Such instances of *shut* might be considered set phrases.)

Another thing to be wary of is that *close* has a homograph (same spelling, different pronunciation) meaning "near".

Comment: Likewise we can "close the deal" - make the deal final (per Webster's Fourth Edition).

Shut is also used in many cases for added emphasis - "Now Jericho was tightly shut up..." and "Please, just shut up"  vs "The gates of Jericho were closed" and "Please, close your mouth" (which might not be in reference to speaking but say maybe chewing with your mouth open).

There are many uses for both that are the same, indeed Webster's Fourth does have one of the definitions of close being shut.  But each has alternate usages that aren't related the other.

Comment: I always also assumed "close" carried a softer tone whereas "shut" is more harsh.

Comment: There are definitely dialects of British English where "shut" is preferred over "close" in pretty much all instances where it's applicable.

Comment: _lip_ as a metaphor for talking back is commonly used in the US as well.

Comment: @JustinLardinois: Thanks, learn something new every day. Whenever I imagine anyone saying it, it's in a regional English accent.

Answer (score 3):

It would be hard to come up with a comprehensive list. You just have to pay attention to what meanings each as, and see which ones are had by only one. If you want to replace one with the other, you have to check whether the meaning survives. One are to be careful in is phrasal verbs. "shut up" is generally used to mean "be quiet", while "close up", if it's used at all, is used for things like filling in holes. "shut out" means to exclude, while "close out" is used in liquidation sales. "shut in" refers to agoraphobics, "close in" means to get closer.

Also, the past tense  and past participle of "shut" are just "shut", while the past tense of "close" is "closed". So you shouldn't say "The door has been shutted" or "The door has been close".

Answer (score 3):

From other answers we can see that English speakers do not always agree about when these words are used, or should be used, even if we only consider their use in isolation rather than in expressions such as **shut up** and **close down**. I'm hard pressed to explain why I would more usually say

```
the airport was shut
```

rather than

```
the airport was closed
```

though I would view both as formally correct. This may be due to my Yorkshire origins: **shut** sounds stronger in an Yorkshire accent.

If we go back to origins of words I note this [etymology site](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=shut&ref=searchbar_searchhint) has

> Old English scyttan "to put (a bolt) in place so as to fasten a door or gate, bolt, shut to; discharge, pay off," from West Germanic *skutjan (source also of Old Frisian schetta, Middle Dutch schutten "to shut, shut up, obstruct")

and this sense of not only closing, but fixing closed accords with my personal feeling of **shut** as being more forceful than close.

Comment: Indeed, one may close a window, but to also shutter it is to add protection against storms and/or wild animals, so "shut" is stronger than "closed".  The manager closed the restaurant at night, but the health inspector shut it down.

Comment: That is interesting.  As an American hearing `the airport was shut` sounds wrong.  Hearing it was `shut down` sounds fine, though that implies a more out-of-the-ordinary and/or permanent closing than just saying `the airport was closed`.

Comment: I agree that in US usage (specifically New England) shut is stronger. It is also more physical. An airport can be closed in a strictly administrative sense: no airplanes are allowed to land or take off. When I hear that the airport is shut, I picture someone trying to open the terminal door and finding it locked. Similarly, if I hear that an airport was "shut down" I picture physical steps such as parking equipment, turning off lights, and sending non-essential employees home.

Answer (score 2):

I'm here because I'm reading a mystery from 1955 by Patricia Wentworth, The Gazebo, where a character finds a door 'only closed, not shut'. The door is considered not properly shut because the catch hasn't engaged. I have always considered shut and closed interchangeable and do not recollect anyone using it in the manner Wentworth does. I can only assume that the difference in use has been lost in the decades since the book was written, perhaps just as a door just open a little would now probably just be described as 'open' and not 'ajar' , so 'closed' could mean a little bit more closed than ajar?

Comment: Interesting. From what I can tell, M-W seems to support this: [shut](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/shut): vt.  3 : to fasten with a lock or bolt; adj. 1 : closed, fastened, or folded together.

Comment: That's a fascinating usage, and nothing I've ever heard. I'd use either shut or closed to mean "not ajar"; and "latched" to indicate that the mechanism had engaged. And of course "locked" to mean that a key is needed to open it.

Answer (score 0):

To "shutter a window" means to close the panels we call shutters (functional ones now being very rare apart from historic properties), and is orthogonal to "shut the window", which would be taken to refer to the sashes or casements or whatever components the window itself has. (Always bothered me that in The Night Before Christmas, he "Tore open the shutters, and threw up the sash", when being inside the house he must have done them in the opposite order.) And "shuttered" is often used to mean "boarded up" or "closed permanently", as in a failed business. But I would not draw inferences on the use of "shut" from the use of "shutter".

With "shut" vs "shut down", we have the issue of gradual loss of prepositions from idiomatic phrases, which is why in a group of angry people, the Americans are pissed while everyone else is pissed off, until they go get pissed to forget about it.

As for closed vs shut, "shut" is more impactful, a little less polite, a little less formal. I think differences are idiomatic, stylistic, regional and conventional, not structural. I doubt there's a case of either that wouldn't sound normal to some English speaker, somewhere.