# "Pulled open the door" and "pushed shut the door."

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-choice

Why is that "pulled open the door" is a common phrase but not "pushed shut the door?" (In other words, putting "shut" in front of the verb.)

Maybe I'm wrong but "pushed shut the door" sounds a little strange? Why is that?

Comment: It is slightly awkward to *say* the words "pushed shut". It *literally* "sounds a little strange", as you say. Historically "shut" implied the use of a bolt. It was more secure then "close." We *close* our mouths when eating, but "Shut up!" or "Shut your mouth!" means 'stop talking!' Predictably, 'Shut' is from Old English and the more elegant 'Close' from Old French. You may find this helpful: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/200396/what-is-the-difference-between-shut-and-close

Comment: It's worth noting that the two sequences ***pulled open the door*** and ***pulled the door open*** are [equally common.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pulled+open+the+door%2Cpulled+the+door+open&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3)

Comment: ...Also note that there are two different adjectives/adverbs for the "opposite" - ***pushed the door closed*** and ***pushed the door shut*** (which coincidentally are [almost exactly equally popular](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pushed+the+door+closed%2Cpushed+the+door+shut&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpushed%20the%20door%20closed%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpushed%20the%20door%20shut%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cpushed%20the%20door%20closed%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpushed%20the%20door%20shut%3B%2Cc0))

Comment: ...but you're right to pick up on the somewhat quirky fact that you can ***pull open the door*** but idiomatically you don't normally ***push shut the door***.

Comment: There's no such "lop-sidedness" with ***turn on the light / turn the light on***, where both "opposites" *(**turn off the light** / **turn the light off**)* are [perfectly natural.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=turn+on+the+light%2Cturn+the+light+on%2Cturn+off+the+light%2Cturn+the+light+off&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cturn%20on%20the%20light%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cturn%20the%20light%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cturn%20off%20the%20light%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cturn%20the%20light%20off%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: The issue is with shut or open, as you can push open or pull open a door but you cannot pull shut or push shut the door.

Answer (score 1):

I agree; sounds just a bit odd.  Certainly allowable.  Maybe pulled open is just a nice, visually descripting sounding thing.  Closing a door is a little more restrictive; not a lot of ways to do it; it closes on its own with some hydraulics, or you push on it.  It's slower.  But if you open the thing, maybe you just turn the knob and open it a tiny hair.  Pulling it open really means getting the thing open.  I think I've convinced myself, even.

Comment: The whole world is different now.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://speakspeak.com/resources/english-grammar-rules/various-grammar-rules/phrasal-verbs-structure-and-examples) are [a couple of relevant definitions...](https://speakspeak.com/resources/english-grammar-rules/various-grammar-rules/phrasal-verbs-structure-and-examples)

> ***phrasal verb***
> **verb + adverb**  (ex: *throw away*)
> **verb + adverb + preposition** (Ex: *put up with*)

> ***prepositional verb***
> **verb + preposition** (Ex: *look after, look at, wait for, think about, talk about,...*)

---

With a ***phrasal verb*** (verb + adverb), the position of the object (a noun) is flexible, i.e. it can sit either between the verb and the adverb or after the adverb:

> *She took her coat off*
> (The object her coat is between the verb and the adverb.)
> OR
> *She took off her coat*
> (The object her coat is after the adverb.)

With ***prepositional verbs*** (verb + preposition), ***the position of the object***—regardless of whether it’s a noun or pronoun—***is not flexible***. The object must sit ***after the preposition:***

> *We looked after the children*
> <strike>*looked the children after*</strike>
> *We looked after them*
> <strike>*looked them after*</strike>